# How to dynamicly create variables inside a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r

got a list named x which has 25 elements. Each of which is named after a country. Inside each country i have 10-20 variables and i want to create a new one inside each dataframe which uses one already existing variable (lets name it y) to create a new variable.

closest i have come to solving it is using a for loop but using the [[<- creates newvariables outside the list (which is too much of a hustle to put in again) with "[[" in their name.

also assign doesnt work either due to invalid first argument error (propably due to my effort to dynamically create them)

i guess a nested lapply is the best option but being new to R dont know how that would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the `list` with `lapply` and `transform` to create a new variable

```
lapply(lst, transform, newVar = y)
```

Comment: great suggestion! i got that feeling when you write 40 lines and someone suggests 1 line and works better! loving R! also any suggestiongs how i could create more than 1 newVar and name it dynamically?   tried something like:     for (k in 1:6){
  name<-paste("newvar",k,sep="")
  list<-lapply(list,transform,name= y-k)
}

Comment: @Dabligiu Perhaps `lapply(lst, transform, newVar=y, newVar1 = someOtherVar)`

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand your question, could you paste some code and say what you'd like to see. When I have to create variables names dynamically I use trick as the one below:

```
names(tmp) = paste('y', 1:25, sep='')
```

If you search help(names) you should get how to change columns and row names specifically. Paste is just a way to concatenate different types of text you want into your variable names

Comment: sorry for the bad explanation. it seems though akrun has understood and provided exactly the answer i was looking for:)